# How to retrieve recently create/updated blobs from google storage/buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Folks,

I have requirement to retrieve only recent blobs from google cloud storage using python.

currently we are using bucket.list_blobs method, however couldn't find the parameters for time based retrieval...

Please let us know if there is any API to retrieve recent blobs?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files changed after a particular timestamp in Google Cloud Storage Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538197/list-files-changed-after-a-particular-timestamp-in-google-cloud-storage-bucket)

Comment: There's no API method to do what you want. You'll need to loop through each objects in the bucket, get the time created and/or last updated timestamps then subtract it to the current date.

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.updated
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.time_created
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py

Answer (score 0):

We cannot retrieve recent blobs from the GCS. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) explains all the needed information about the Objects: list API, but clearly, the filter, condition and sorting of properties are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Blob objects have time_created property (https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob)

You can use a conditional to retrieve only what you need, such as:

```
blobs = [i for i in bucket.list_blobs() if i.time_created.date() >= datetime(2022,7,26).date()]
```